# String where from JSP is doesn't work at JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
<%for (String st : geocodePhoto.keySet()) {%>


        alert(<%=st%>); // not work
        alert(<%=geocodePhoto.get(st).getX()%>); // work fine
        alert(<%=geocodePhoto.get(st).getY()%>); // work fine
        alert(<%=geocodePhoto.get(st).getDate()%>); // not work
    <%}%>
```

getX is return double value and getDate return String value like 'yy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss'

st has same form 'yy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss'

2,3 line alert is work fine but 1,4 line alert is doesn't work

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<%= %>` tag in JSP acts as if it calls [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) with the expression in the tag as the parameter, and writes the returned value to the output.  So, your generated JavaScript source probably looks something like this:

```
alert(13:11:23 10:30:17);
alert(-0.06);
alert(51.5);
alert(13:11:23 10:30:17);
```

You're trying to pass text to the first and last calls to `alert`, but you aren't putting the text in quotes - so, you're getting a syntax error.  The middle two calls are writing numbers into your JavaScript source - as a numeric constant is valid JavaScript, they work without being quoted.

So, your JSP code should look like this:

```
alert("<%=st%>");
alert(<%=geocodePhoto.get(st).getX()%>);
alert(<%=geocodePhoto.get(st).getY()%>);
alert("<%=geocodePhoto.get(st).getDate()%>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass string through  `""`

```
 alert("<%=st%>");
alert("<%=geocodePhoto.get(st).getDate()%>");
```